# What does `&'a mut` mean when in the impl definition outside the generic parameter space?

Tags: rust

For example, we seem to have 3 different implementations of the `IntoIterator` trait for `HashMap` in the Rust std lib.

```
impl<'a, K, V, S> IntoIterator for &'a HashMap<K, V, S> {
  type Item = (&'a K, &'a V);
  type IntoIter = Iter<'a, K, V>;

  fn into_iter(self) -> Iter<'a, K, V> {
      self.iter()
  }
}

impl<'a, K, V, S> IntoIterator for &'a mut HashMap<K, V, S> {
  type Item = (&'a K, &'a mut V);
  type IntoIter = IterMut<'a, K, V>;

  fn into_iter(self) -> IterMut<'a, K, V> {
      self.iter_mut()
  }
}

impl<K, V, S> IntoIterator for HashMap<K, V, S> {
  type Item = (K, V);
  type IntoIter = IntoIter<K, V>;
}
```

What does `&'a HashMap` or `&'a mut HashMap` mean in this context, where it is appearing at the "class level" and outside of the `<>` angle brackets for generic parameters. I understand that `&` means take a reference, and `'a` is a lifetime, and `mut` is for mutability, but under what contexts does it apply when defined like this? I am used to seeing those constructs in function parameters, but not here.

Comment: *it is appearing at the "class level" and outside of the <> angle brackets for generic parameters* - Regarding the lifetime appearing outside `<>` angle brackets, that's just special syntax for references. If you were to trivially wrap the reference `&'a HashMap<K, V, S>` in a struct, let's call it `Ref`, you'd have to associate that struct with a lifetime, and then you'd implement `IntoIterator` for it using the expected syntax: `impl<'a, K, V, S> IntoIterator for Ref<'a, K, V, S>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impl keyword takes a `unsafe? impl GenericParams? !? TypePath for Type` as per the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html). If we break down your example:

`impl<'a, K, V, S> IntoIterator for &'a HashMap<K, V, S>`: We have `<'a, K, V, S>` being *GenericParams*, and `IntoIterator` being the *TypePath*. This means `&'a HashMap<K, V, S>` is a *Type*. notable, HashMap is not the type, the type is the full reference+lifetime+typename. If we look at an example such as:

```rust
let h = HashMap::new();
let rh = &h;
```

In this case `rh` will have type type `&'a HashMap`, and so the first implementation of the IntoIterator will apply to it.

Similarly `&'a mut HashMap` is a type. In an example such as:

```rust
let mut h = HashMap::new();
let mut rh = &h;
```

`rh` would be of type `&'a mut HashMap`.

Why do we want to have specialised implementations? If we look carefully we can see that a value returned by a mutable HashMap will be itself by mutable `Item = (&'a K, &'a mut V);`. Similarly, in case where your type is a reference to a HashMap, we deal with references to values and keys. So the implementation has a slightly different semantic, depending if the collection is a reference or mutable.